# enable cors in Azure blob storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

Can someone please let me know how to enable cors in Azure blob storage ? I tried the following but its not working

```
         ServiceProperties propers = new ServiceProperties();
        CorsRule cr = new CorsRule();
        List<String> allowedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
        allowedHeaders.add(CorsHttpMethods.PUT.name());
        allowedHeaders.add(CorsHttpMethods.POST.name());
        allowedHeaders.add(CorsHttpMethods.DELETE.name());
        allowedHeaders.add(CorsHttpMethods.GET.name());
        cr.setAllowedHeaders(allowedHeaders);
        List<String> allowedOrigin = new ArrayList<String>();
        allowedOrigin.add("*");
        cr.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigin);
        cr.setMaxAgeInSeconds(600);
        CorsProperties corsprop = new CorsProperties();
        corsprop.getCorsRules().add(cr);

        blobClient.uploadServiceProperties(propers);
```

This work for me as below

```
   private static ServiceProperties getCORS() {
    ServiceProperties propers = new ServiceProperties();
    CorsProperties corsprop = propers.getCors();

    CorsRule cr = new CorsRule();

    List<String> allowedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    allowedHeaders.add("x-ms-*");
    List<String> exposedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    exposedHeaders.add("x-ms-*");

    cr.setAllowedHeaders(allowedHeaders);
    cr.setExposedHeaders(exposedHeaders);
    EnumSet<CorsHttpMethods> allowedMethod = EnumSet.of(CorsHttpMethods.PUT);
    cr.setAllowedMethods(allowedMethod);

    List<String> allowedOrigin = new ArrayList<String>();
    allowedOrigin.add("*");
    cr.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigin);
    cr.setMaxAgeInSeconds(600);

    corsprop.getCorsRules().add(cr);

    //corsprop.getCorsRules().add(cr);
    propers.setCors(corsprop);
    return propers;
}
```

Now I am able to set using the following code.I am able to use it, when i upload files from a javascript client created by Gaurav here : http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);


        ServiceProperties propers = getCORS();

        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = createPolicy();

        blobClient.uploadServiceProperties(propers);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's not working"? Are you getting any error?

Comment: update my code in question. I have one more question though. How do i enable CORS on the whole container as a one time activity using java ?

Comment: `How do i enable CORS on the whole container as a one time activity using java` - CORS is set at blob storage level and not container level. Once you have set CORS, you don't have to do it for each container. Are you getting an error in uploading blobs?

Comment: Gaurav, Do you have any client which does parallel upload. I am following your html javascript client but it uploads one chunk at a time. please advice

Comment: Unfortunately no. We did parallel uploads in our product however in there we're uploading multiple files in parallel where in each file one chunk is uploaded at a time.

Comment: I am getting this in Chrome and IE 10 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin.....is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. Any idea ?

Comment: In your CORS settings, change allowed headers and exposed headers to `*` and that should take care of the problem.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, can we chat if possible. I need to resolve this